# How can i explicitly check request content-type is matching with actual content in Spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, owasp

I want to validate my request content-type is matching with my request body or not?
I am trying to implement the OWASP Rest security standard.

Which says :[image: Json Mismatch]

13.2.5 Verify that REST services explicitly check the incoming Content-Type to be the expected one, such as application/XML or application/JSON.

In the below image the content type is JSON but the request is in XML.Still it's working fine.

My Controller code:-

```
@RestController
public class TestController {

@PostMapping(path="/hello",consumes = "application/json")
public Map<String,String> hello(Master ecm){
    Map<String,String> m=new HashMap<>() ;
    m.put("message", "hello!");
    return m;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring annotations provide a specific attribute for that. It is called consumes.

Here is an example

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.SELECT_TYPE_HERE)
```

specific example

```
@PostMapping(consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
```

Comment: I know about the Consumes and Produces, But if I am sending a content-type as application/XML in request and my request body is in JSON format, that checking how I can achieve it?

Comment: @tusharwason That's already there for you from Spring. It will provide automatically the right `message body reader` or `message body writer` to parse the request or response depending on the info you provided on `consumes` and `produces`. If that `message body reader` or `message body writer` fails you know that something is messed up

Comment: Thanks, @Boug, Just wanted to know if there is any equivalent of the same in sails js too?

Comment: Can you look into the question again I have updated It with Images and Code.